# find all entire functions such that $f(0)=1$ and $\lvert f(z)\rvert \le 2 \lvert z^\frac{3}{2} \rvert-1$ for $\lvert z \rvert \ge 2$

Tags: complex-analysis

How do I use Taylor series in this properly?

We know $f(z) = 1 + \sum_1^\infty a_nz^n$ and $$\lvert f(z) \rvert \le 2R^\frac{3}{2}-1 $$ where $R > 2$

By Cauchy inequality for integrals, $$\lvert f'(z) \rvert \le \dfrac{1!\  (2R^\frac{3}{2}-1)}{R-R_0} $$ where $R_0 < R$

and $$\lvert f''(z) \rvert \le \dfrac{2!\  (2R^\frac{3}{2}-1)}{(R-R_0)^2} $$

Taking limit $R \to \infty $ gives $\lvert f''(z) \rvert \le 0$ which leads me to say that $f'(z) = c$ implying $\lvert f(z) \rvert = cz + d$ Using the condition in question we get $d = 0$ ?

How do I proceed further using Louvilles theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\displaystyle |f(z)|\le2|z|^{3/2}-1\le 2|z|^{3/2}$. By Liouville's theorem , $f$ is a polynomial of degree $[3/2]=1$. So  take, $f(z)=az+b$. $f(0)=1$ gives $b=1$. Then $f(z)=az+1$. Again , $\displaystyle f\left(\frac{1}{2^{2/3}}\right)=0$ gives , $a=-2^{2/3}$.

Hence , $f(z)=1-2^{2/3}z$.

Comment: Where did the step about $f(2^{-2/3})$ come from?

Comment: Oops. I got the answer. It comes from the inequality when we equate it to zero

Comment: Yeh...You are correct..